# Brute Force Decrypt VeraCrypt - No Rescue Disk - Password Fails

Tags: brute-force, decryption, veracrypt

My PC has failed in some way, as the PC was off when I checked it. I checked the CPU temperature etc., and runs at 54deg C in the BIOS, and does not fail when left on. So, I am not sure if it is a hardware issue.

The hard disk is encrypted with VeraCrypt, and despite entering the password it will not boot/decrypt, and I do not have the VeraCypt rescue disk for this specific disk. This is the second time a WD drive refuses to boot/decrypt – I suspect it has corrupted the relevant hard disk sector.

I know what the contents of the hard disk is – as I have a backup from some time ago.

So, the only alternative is to attempt to decrypt using a brute force algorithm – which is nigh on impossible.

Will knowing what the hard disk contains be of any benefit?

And if so – are there any free decryption programs that can use known hard disk contents to accelerate the hard disk decryption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, knowing the encrypted contents won't help.

This is called a known-plaintext attack and good ciphers should not break when confronted with one.